# JavaScript algorithm to generate 2d array of numbers, only puts 0 and -1

Tags: javascript, arrays

I don't have a lot of knowledge about javascript so sorry if my way of doing is not the best for the language.
I have this algorithm that represents a grid of users as a 2d array. It receives as parameter the number of columns and rows and the number of users to represent. The places where there aren't any users, it is represented with a -1 and a user is represented by their number.

```
const generateIndividual = (
      numberOfUsers,
      numberOfRows,
      numberOfColumns
    ) => {
      let allReadyUsedPoints = [];
      let individual = [];
      for (let i = 0; i < numberOfRows; i++) {
        let thisRow = [];

        for (let j = 0; j < numberOfColumns; j++) {
          let generatedNumber = getRandomNumber(-10, numberOfUsers);
          while (allReadyUsedPoints.indexOf(generatedNumber) >= 0) {
            generatedNumber = getRandomNumber(-10, numberOfUsers);
          }
          if (generatedNumber >= 0) {
            allReadyUsedPoints.push(generatedNumber);
            thisRow.push(generatedNumber);
          } else {
            thisRow.push(-1);
          }  
        }
        individual[i] = thisRow;
      }
      console.log(individual);
      return checkIfIndividualIsVallid(
        allReadyUsedPoints,
        individual,
        numberOfUsers
      );
    };
```

but when I put the info in the 2d array every number is replaced with a 0 except for the -1.
Result for a 10x10 grid with 8 users.
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j7PMz.png)

on top there is every array individual and in bottom is the 2d array

Comment: Could it be that `checkIfIndividualIsVallid` is modifying the rows? Can you share that function's code? For example, there could be an accidental `if (individual[i][j] = 1) { }` instead of `if (individual[i][j] == 1) { }`.

Comment: the console.log() is above that method so I didn't put it there to avoid confusion

Comment: If you're sure it's not `checkIfIndividualIsVallid`, I'm afraid the problem is not reproducable. Here's your code running without the problem you describe: https://jsfiddle.net/yapcwuv6/